# Отладка виртуальной функции

Tags: c++builder, отладка, borland, c++, soap

Пытаюсь через `Borland C++ Builder` использовать веб сервис. Воспользовался стандартной генерацией классов и интерфейсов через встроеный в билдер визард по wsdl. Когда вызываю метод, который не принимает параметров, проблем нет, но при вызове метода с параметрами вылетает исключение. Отловил `WireShark`'ом пакеты и понял в чём дело, в SOAP обёртке запроса, которую генерирует билдер в теге с передаваемой переменной отсутствует `namespace` (`xmlns`), вот мне как то надо перехватить дебагером исполнение кода, который отвечает за построение xml, но беда в том, что этот код зашит в виртуальной функции (`virtual AnsiString <имя_метода_веб_сервиса>(const AnsiString <имя_переменной>) = 0;`). **Как я могу отловить исполнение нужного мне участка кода?**

Comment: в этом WSDL Import куча настроек в Options. попробуйте поискать там, скорее всего не надо так глубоко лезть во внутренности, кроме того какие-то настройки можно передать со своим HTTPRIO (если не указать его, он создается в процессе).  
ЗЫ с вашей проблемой не сталкивался, но были варианты, когда с одними настройками сервис тоже не принимал запросы, с другим все проходило нормально, зависит от вендора сервиса.

Comment: Просто, что бы было: сервис на `JavaEE` на `JBoosAS7`.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, пощёлкал настройки, их там не так уж и много, не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> пощёлкал настройки, их там не так уж и много, не помогло.

да, на все возможные случаи настроек нету )

Сам запрос вы можете поправить в [HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Rio_TRIO_OnBeforeExecute.html)
То есть, создаете [HTTPRIO](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SOAPHTTPClient_THTTPRIO.html) и передаете в функцию создания соединения с сервисом.
Что типа:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var 
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  SL.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  SL.Text := WideReplaceStr(SL.Text,'что-то','на что-то');
  SOAPRequest.Size := Length(SL.Text);
  SL.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  SL.Free;
end;

// где-то при старте формы
HTTPRIO:=THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute := HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute;
ws:=GetMyWebServiceSoap(false,'',HTTPRIO);

// где-то по клику, например
ws.MyMethod(...);
```

ЗЫ имею дело с delphi, под билдер синтаксис соответственно сишный.
ЗЗЫ код не проверял, но этот путь должен быть самым простым.

Comment: смешалось wide и ansi. ну там уже, понятно, надо будет решить по ходу дела что надо...

Comment: Суть ясна, но не могу перенести этот код на С++, чтоб компилировалось, кто нибудь на С++ пишет? Я не знаю как правильно сигнатуру метода прописать для HTTPRIO->OnBeforeExecute. А в гугле, как назло, все примеры на делфи.

Comment: @KorobOK, добавьте на форму HTTPRIO (на закладке WebServices есть такой компонент), создайте для него соответствующий обработчик... я привел пример динамического создания компонента, можно и без динамики обойтись.

Comment: Проблема не в создании экземпляра `HTTPRIO`, а в методе, который бы подошёл на роль делегата для `onBeforeExecute`: `void TRIO::OnBeforeExecute (__fastcall*(__closure)(const AnsiString, WideString &))(const AnsiString, WideString &)`

Comment: @KorobOK, так вы добавьте обработчик, увидите сигнатуру, билдер сам вам создать метод с нужной сигнатурой.

Comment: Done. Сигнатуру метода увидел, а вот сам процесс связывания созданного объекта и этого метода не могу найти. В C#, например, любое изменение свойств объекта порождает генерацию кода, который меняет эти свойства сразу после выделения памяти в процессе инициализации, уверен, C++ Builder поступает так же, но в отличие от C# (Visual Studio любой версии), C++ Builder старательно прячет этот функционал, не могу найти, куда именно.

Comment: @KorobOK, не совсем вас понимаю, но попробуйте просто присвоить свойству метод.

Comment: Нашёл источник проблемы, оказалось, что класс, в котором я создал метод для `onBeforeExecute`, не был статическим, а в контексте присвоения экземпляра этого класса у меня не было. Собственно, несмотря на то, что про отладку виртуальных функций никто ничего так и не написал, проблема решена. Думаю, не будет сильно большим оффтопом, если кто нибудь очень добрый скинет в эту тему ссылку(и) на какой нибудь хороший мануал по `HTTPRIO`.